# How to speed up nested for loops in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, nested

## I have the following python code:

```
for i in tqdm(df.index):
    des1 = descriptors_1[i]
    for j in df.columns:
        des2 = descriptors_1[j]
        #avoid match with same descriptor
        if np.array_equal(des1, des2) == False:  
            # BFMatcher with default params
            bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_L1)
            matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

            # Apply ratio test
            # Consider only good matches that pass the ratio test
            good = []
            for m,n in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.8*n.distance:
                    good.append([m])
            df.loc[i][j] = len(good)
        else:
            df.loc[i][j] = np.nan
```

df is an empty dataframe composed by NxN element where N is the number of element of descriptors_1. The code takes hours to run beause the table is very big . Is it possible to somehow speed up this code?

Comment: Hi, have you tried [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like Joblib to take advantage of your CPU's cores and run the code with multiprocessing.

Here is a possible way to do this with joblib:

```
pip install joblib
```

After installing, here is how you could change your code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
#import any other libraries left

def match_descriptors(des1, row_index, df, descriptors_1):
    for j in df.columns:
        des2 = descriptors_1[j]
        #avoid match with same descriptor
        if np.array_equal(des1, des2) == False:  
            # BFMatcher with default params
            bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_L1)
            matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

            # Apply ratio test
            # Consider only good matches that pass the ratio test
            good = []
            for m,n in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.8*n.distance:
                    good.append([m])
            df.loc[i][j] = len(good)
        else:
            df.loc[i][j] = np.nan


descriptors_1 = [1, 2, 3] # define your descriptor

N = len(descriptors_1)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(N), columns=range(N))

# Define the number of parallel jobs to use. You can try out on different numbers but it can be <= cpu cores.
#to check the cpu cores, you can use: os.cpu_count().

n_jobs = 4

# Run the loop in parallel
results = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(
    delayed(match_descriptors)(descriptors_1[i], i, df, descriptors_1) for i in tqdm(df.index))
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: itertools does not provide multi-processing.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it out. I read somewhere that we can use multiprocessing.pool and itertools to work in a nested loop case.

Comment: Yes, you are thinking of itertools `product` which can replace some nested loops; see [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and many examples in SO